# Given 2 marginal distributions build a bivariate joint-distribution with certain characteristics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim \operatorname{U}(0,1)$, I need to build 3 joint distributions, one where they are independent (This is trivial, it's just the product of tha marginals), one where they are positive correlated and another where they are negative correlated.

I'd like to employ copulas instead of simple variable transformations, but I don't know how to proceed. Can i choose any type of copula? How i do choose a certain level of correlation? I'd like some insight on the problem, please.

Comment: Have you tried simple algebraic combinations of X and Y?

Comment: I thought of that, but as I'm studying copulas I'd like to apply the concepts. I will edit the post to make that explicit.

Comment: You might try $$Y=e^{-X/\lambda}$$ and $$Y=1-e^{-X/\lambda}$$